# How to achieve below logic with php

Tags: php, logic

I need to get out put as below:

```
  1234
  123
  12
  1
  12
  123
  1234
```

My try

```
<?php
$n=4;


for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){
    for($j=$i;$j<=$n;$j++){
       if($i==4){
        echo $j-3;
     }
    else if($i==2){
       echo $j-1;
     }
    else if($i==3){
      echo $j-2;
    } else {
       echo $j;
      }
    }
        echo "<br>";
}
for($i=4;$i>=1;$i--){
    for($j=$i;$j<=$n;$j++){
       if($i==4){
        echo $j-3;
     }
    else if($i==2){
       echo $j-1;
     }
    else if($i==3){
      echo $j-2;
    } else {
       echo "";
      }
    }
     echo "<br>";
}
```

Can any one suggest me best way to achieve above logic.

Comment: sounds like a homework assignment

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i tried i will update the question

Comment: @sickest: Work is work, whether we do it in home or office.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Can you plz suggest me best way to achieve it.

Comment: It's good to see what you've tried. Your code is very close to the correct output. However you print 1 twice - if you try and shorten your first loop `$i < n` you will find that you get the correct output. That being said, your solution is rather messy and you can try and write a cleaner approach as per my suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: treat it as a string rather than a number, and simply print out the first x digits each time.

ie, the whole string might be '1234' and you print out the first 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4 characters respectively.

Since it does sound like a homework question I won't provide a complete answer, but here are some references that might help you.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

https://www.php.net/substr

Answer (score 1):

You have your input ("1234"), you just need 2 for/foreach-loops which iterate from n-1 to 0 and the other one from 1 to n-1, and while you do the for/foreach, just give them the substring of that input you have.

That is all you need to do